# numpy append 3D matrices

Tags: numpy

What happens when I `numpy.append` two 3-D matrices?

Ex. 
`a` is a matrix of shape (662, 887, 3), `b` is a matrix of shape `(77, 103, 100)`.

I used `numpy.append` to create a matrix `c`, which is of shape `(2554682,)`.

What does this mean? What happened here?

Comment: What did you expect?  The 2 arrays don't have any dimensions in common.

Comment: "Expect nothing and appreciate everything".

Comment: The docs mention this flattening.  This is another example of how `np.append` is dangerous to beginners.  `np.concatenate` would have raised an error, saying the dimensions don't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(`662` * `887` * `3`) + (`77` * `103` * `100`) = `2554682`

It squished all the elements into a 1-Dimensional vector with the amount of elements being the sum of the amount of elements of `a` and `b`.